# How to install sensplit on google colab?

Tags: python, time-series, google-colaboratory, sensors, train-test-split

How to install sensplit on google colab ?
I already cloned the git repository on google colab[image] but I couldn't use the sensplit package , when I run the !pip install sensplit it returns errors.
Please, I need a hint.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, clone `sensplit` from `git`.

```
!git clone https://github.com/mmalekzadeh/sensplit
```

Then, change directory to the `SenSplit` folder and `run the install command`:

```
cd sensplit

!python setup.py install
```

So in `colab` steps,

[image]